# make a dictionary based on a list and pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like that
df

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   1   1   1   0   0 
1   1   1   0   0   0 
2   1   0   0   1   1 
3   1   1   0   1   0 
4   0   1   1   0   0
```

and also I have a dictionary that looks like

```
dict = {(1, 2): 0,
       (1, 3): 0,
       (1, 4): 0,
       (1, 5): 0,
       (2, 1): 0,
       (2, 3): 0,
       (2, 4): 0,
       (2, 5): 0,
       (3, 1): 0,
       (3, 2): 0,
       (3, 4): 0,
       (3, 5): 0,
       (4, 1): 0,
       (4, 2): 0,
       (4, 3): 0,
       (4, 5): 0,
       (5, 1): 0,
       (5, 2): 0,
       (5, 3): 0,
       (5, 4): 0}
```

I want two things:
first if key (i,j) = key (j,i) remove it ex: key (1,2) and key (2,1)
I want to remove (2,1) so the final dict will be

```
dict = {(1, 2): 0,
       (1, 3): 0,
       (1, 4): 0,
       (1, 5): 0,
       (2, 3): 0,
       (2, 4): 0,
       (2, 5): 0,
       (3, 4): 0,
       (3, 5): 0,
       (4, 5): 0}
```

second I want to update values with respect to data frames df
if columns that are the keys in dict have the same value which is 1 count it
ex:  key(1,2) for columns 1 & 2 have 1 in the same row 3 times so the value of key(1,2) will be updated to 3 and so on..
so the final dict will be

```
dict = {(1, 2): 3,
       (1, 3): 1,
       (1, 4): 2,
       (1, 5): 1,
       (2, 3): 2,
       (2, 4): 1,
       (2, 5): 0,
       (3, 4): 0,
       (3, 5): 0,
       (4, 5): 1}
```

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to initiate a dict, just use a double for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv=StringIO("""
   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   1   1   0   0 
1   1   1   0   0   0 
2   1   0   0   1   1 
3   1   1   0   1   0 
4   0   1   1   0   0""")
sample = pd.read_csv(csv,sep='\s+')

col_com={}
for i in range(sample.shape[1]-1):
    for j in range(i+1,sample.shape[1]):
        col_com[(i+1,j+1)]=sum(sample.iloc[:,i]&sample.iloc[:,j])
col_com
```

The result is :

```
{(1, 2): 3,
 (1, 3): 1,
 (1, 4): 2,
 (1, 5): 1,
 (2, 3): 2,
 (2, 4): 1,
 (2, 5): 0,
 (3, 4): 0,
 (3, 5): 0,
 (4, 5): 1}
```

Wish it helps

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
d_1 = {(1, 2): 0,
       (1, 3): 0,
       (1, 4): 0,
       (1, 5): 0,
       (2, 1): 0,
       (2, 3): 0,
       (2, 4): 0,
       (2, 5): 0,
       (3, 1): 0,
       (3, 2): 0,
       (3, 4): 0,
       (3, 5): 0,
       (4, 1): 0,
       (4, 2): 0,
       (4, 3): 0,
       (4, 5): 0,
       (5, 1): 0,
       (5, 2): 0,
       (5, 3): 0,
       (5, 4): 0}

new_keys = []
for k in d_1:
    invert = (k[1], k[0])
    if invert not in new_keys:
        new_keys.append(k)

d_2 = {}
for k in new_keys:
    d_2[k] = d_1[k]

df = [
  [1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
  [1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
  [1,  0,  0,  1,  1],
  [1,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [0,  1,  1,  0,  0],
]

d_3 = {}
for k in d_2:
    v = 0
    c1, c2 = k[0] - 1, k[1] - 1
    for line in df:
        if line[c1] == line[c2]:
            v += 1
    d_3[k] = v

print(d_3)
```

output:

```
{(1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 1, (1, 4): 3, (1, 5): 2, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 1, (2, 5): 0, (3, 4): 1, (3, 5): 2, (4, 5): 4}
```

(looks like your example has at least one mistake: your result (1,4) should be 3, not 2, since rows 2, 3 and 4 match on columns 1 and 4.)